# FFMPEG Command Works, then stops

Tags: video, ffmpeg, conversion, command-line

When I use ffmpeg with this command:

```
$ ffmpeg -i ~/Desktop/The_Karate_Kid_2010.mkv -c:v libx264 -c:a libfdk_aac -c:s mov_text ~/Desktop/The_Karate_Kid_2010.mp4
```

It works, until this error appears:

```
Error while opening encoder for output stream #0:2 - maybe incorrect parameters such as bit_rate, rate, width or height
```

What should I do to fix this?
Here is the output:

```
ffmpeg -i ~/Desktop/The_Karate_Kid_2010.mkv -c:v libx264 -c:a libfdk_aac -c:s mov_text ~/Desktop/file.mp4
ffmpeg version 3.3.3 Copyright (c) 2000-2017 the FFmpeg developers
  built with Apple LLVM version 8.1.0 (clang-802.0.42)
  configuration: --prefix=/usr/local/Cellar/ffmpeg/3.3.3 --enable-shared --enable-pthreads --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --enable-hardcoded-tables --enable-avresample --cc=clang --host-cflags= --host-ldflags= --enable-libass --enable-libfdk-aac --enable-libfreetype --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libxvid --enable-opencl --disable-lzma --enable-nonfree --enable-vda
  libavutil      55. 58.100 / 55. 58.100
  libavcodec     57. 89.100 / 57. 89.100
  libavformat    57. 71.100 / 57. 71.100
  libavdevice    57.  6.100 / 57.  6.100
  libavfilter     6. 82.100 /  6. 82.100
  libavresample   3.  5.  0 /  3.  5.  0
  libswscale      4.  6.100 /  4.  6.100
  libswresample   2.  7.100 /  2.  7.100
  libpostproc    54.  5.100 / 54.  5.100
Input #0, matroska,webm, from '/Users/Henry/Desktop/The_Karate_Kid_2010.mkv':
  Metadata:
    title           : Karate Kid, The
    encoder         : libmakemkv v1.10.7 (1.3.3/1.4.4) darwin(x64-release)
    creation_time   : 2017-10-01T21:56:39.000000Z
  Duration: 02:20:01.99, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 4488 kb/s
    Chapter #0:0: start 0.000000, end 423.055967
    Metadata:
      title           : Chapter 01
    Chapter #0:1: start 423.055967, end 627.259967
    Metadata:
      title           : Chapter 02
    Chapter #0:2: start 627.259967, end 907.273033
    Metadata:
      title           : Chapter 03
    Chapter #0:3: start 907.273033, end 1194.560033
    Metadata:
      title           : Chapter 04
    Chapter #0:4: start 1194.560033, end 1468.233433
    Metadata:
      title           : Chapter 05
    Chapter #0:5: start 1468.233433, end 1857.288767
    Metadata:
      title           : Chapter 06
    Chapter #0:6: start 1857.288767, end 2094.058633
    Metadata:
      title           : Chapter 07
    Chapter #0:7: start 2094.058633, end 2390.321267
    Metadata:
      title           : Chapter 08
    Chapter #0:8: start 2390.321267, end 2797.895100
    Metadata:
      title           : Chapter 09
    Chapter #0:9: start 2797.895100, end 2993.357033
    Metadata:
      title           : Chapter 10
    Chapter #0:10: start 2993.357033, end 3295.992700
    Metadata:
      title           : Chapter 11
    Chapter #0:11: start 3295.992700, end 3615.945667
    Metadata:
      title           : Chapter 12
    Chapter #0:12: start 3615.945667, end 3878.624750
    Metadata:
      title           : Chapter 13
    Chapter #0:13: start 3878.624750, end 4187.983800
    Metadata:
      title           : Chapter 14
    Chapter #0:14: start 4187.983800, end 4470.599467
    Metadata:
      title           : Chapter 15
    Chapter #0:15: start 4470.599467, end 4825.587433
    Metadata:
      title           : Chapter 16
    Chapter #0:16: start 4825.587433, end 5062.690967
    Metadata:
      title           : Chapter 17
    Chapter #0:17: start 5062.690967, end 5444.372267
    Metadata:
      title           : Chapter 18
    Chapter #0:18: start 5444.372267, end 5734.995933
    Metadata:
      title           : Chapter 19
    Chapter #0:19: start 5734.995933, end 6105.065633
    Metadata:
      title           : Chapter 20
    Chapter #0:20: start 6105.065633, end 6418.678933
    Metadata:
      title           : Chapter 21
    Chapter #0:21: start 6418.678933, end 6625.585633
    Metadata:
      title           : Chapter 22
    Chapter #0:22: start 6625.585633, end 6980.406767
    Metadata:
      title           : Chapter 23
    Chapter #0:23: start 6980.406767, end 7140.666867
    Metadata:
      title           : Chapter 24
    Chapter #0:24: start 7140.666867, end 7438.197433
    Metadata:
      title           : Chapter 25
    Chapter #0:25: start 7438.197433, end 7875.534333
    Metadata:
      title           : Chapter 26
    Chapter #0:26: start 7875.534333, end 7977.302667
    Metadata:
      title           : Chapter 27
    Chapter #0:27: start 7977.302667, end 8401.993600
    Metadata:
      title           : Chapter 28
    Stream #0:0(eng): Video: mpeg2video (Main), yuv420p(tv, top first), 720x480 [SAR 32:27 DAR 16:9], SAR 186:157 DAR 279:157, 29.97 fps, 29.97 tbr, 1k tbn, 59.94 tbc
    Metadata:
      BPS-eng         : 4096383
      DURATION-eng    : 02:20:01.993600000
      NUMBER_OF_FRAMES-eng: 201483
      NUMBER_OF_BYTES-eng: 4302223608
      SOURCE_ID-eng   : 0100E0
      _STATISTICS_WRITING_APP-eng: MakeMKV v1.10.7 darwin(x64-release)
      _STATISTICS_WRITING_DATE_UTC-eng: 2017-10-01 21:56:39
      _STATISTICS_TAGS-eng: BPS DURATION NUMBER_OF_FRAMES NUMBER_OF_BYTES SOURCE_ID
    Stream #0:1(eng): Audio: ac3, 48000 Hz, 5.1(side), fltp, 384 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      title           : Surround 5.1
      BPS-eng         : 384000
      DURATION-eng    : 02:20:01.952000000
      NUMBER_OF_FRAMES-eng: 262561
      NUMBER_OF_BYTES-eng: 403293696
      SOURCE_ID-eng   : 0180BD
      _STATISTICS_WRITING_APP-eng: MakeMKV v1.10.7 darwin(x64-release)
      _STATISTICS_WRITING_DATE_UTC-eng: 2017-10-01 21:56:39
      _STATISTICS_TAGS-eng: BPS DURATION NUMBER_OF_FRAMES NUMBER_OF_BYTES SOURCE_ID
    Stream #0:2(eng): Subtitle: dvd_subtitle, 720x480 (default)
    Metadata:
      BPS-eng         : 2984
      DURATION-eng    : 02:12:24.359400000
      NUMBER_OF_FRAMES-eng: 1051
      NUMBER_OF_BYTES-eng: 2963824
      SOURCE_ID-eng   : 0120BD
      _STATISTICS_WRITING_APP-eng: MakeMKV v1.10.7 darwin(x64-release)
      _STATISTICS_WRITING_DATE_UTC-eng: 2017-10-01 21:56:39
      _STATISTICS_TAGS-eng: BPS DURATION NUMBER_OF_FRAMES NUMBER_OF_BYTES SOURCE_ID
File '/Users/Henry/Desktop/file.mp4' already exists. Overwrite ? [y/N] y
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (mpeg2video (native) -> h264 (libx264))
  Stream #0:1 -> #0:1 (ac3 (native) -> aac (libfdk_aac))
  Stream #0:2 -> #0:2 (dvd_subtitle (dvdsub) -> mov_text (native))
Error while opening encoder for output stream #0:2 - maybe incorrect parameters such as bit_rate, rate, width or height
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`dvd_subtitle` indicates an image-based subtitle. You can skip it, or overlay it on the video, or convert it to a text subtitle.

To skip it, add `-map -s`.

To overlay it, add `-filter_complex "[0:0]yadif[v];[v][0:2]overlay"`

To convert to text subtitle, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/36327919/5726027